# How to intersect 3 dataframes of the same dimensions and output a dataframe of common occurrences in at least 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes of the same dimensions. I would like to find common occurrences (1s and -1s) in at least 2 out of the 3 dataframes. I want an output dataframe of the same dimensions in which the elements are in at least two dataframes.

I have written the following example for everyone to understand the problem. In the example I want to find in which positions there is a 1 or a -1 in at least two dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

A= {'a': [0, '.', 0, -1],'b': [0, '.', 1, 0], 'c':[1,'.', 0, 1]   }
A = pd.DataFrame(data=A)

    a  b  c
0   0  0  1
1   .  .  .
2   0  1  0
3  -1  0  1

B= {'a': [0, '.', 0, -1],'b': [1, '.', 1, 0], 'c':[1,'.', 0, -1]   }
B = pd.DataFrame(data=B)

B
    a  b   c
0   0  1   1
1   .  .   .
2   0  1   0
3  -1  0  -1

C = {'a': [0, '.', 0, 0],'b': [1, '.', 1, 0], 'c':[0,'.', 0, 0]   }
C = pd.DataFrame(data=C)

C
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  .  .  .
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  0
```

The desired output would be:

```
    a  b  c
0   0  1  1
1   .  .  .
2   0  1  0
3  -1  0  0
```

So if there is more than one 1 or more than one -1 the result in the output dataframe is 1 or -1 respectively. If there is just one 1 or -1 the result in the output dataframe is 0.

I have kept the dots as they are in the original dataframe but they are insignificant for the problem as they are the same in all three dataframes, always.

I have tried few things but none of them worked.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why dots in your dataframe? What is the range of values (-1, 0, 1)?

Comment: Hi, the original dataframes have dots, 0, 1 and -1, meaning different things, although they are not important here I wanted to keep them.

Comment: Just to clarify: If the value at the given position in 2 or more of the dataframes is `0`, _or_ if the values between all three dataframes do not match at that position, then you want the output dataframe to have a `0` at that position?

Comment: are the dots at the same position in the 3 dataframes? if no can you specify how to handle a case with a dot, 0 and 1?

Comment: how excatly the result is determined for each 'cell'? For instance for ['c'][3] there are 3 different values: A:1, B:-1, C:0 why is the result 0 ?

Comment: @hpchavaz, it only takes the value if the occurance is at least 2.

Comment: @Marco_CH , but how the result value (0) is computed in this case ?

Comment: If there is no value with an occurance of at least two then its always 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the underlying numpy arrays to count the values per value and use `numpy.select` to map an arbitrary number of choices. For are treated here independently but could also be added as a value to check.

```
dfs = [A,B,C]
vals = [1, -1]

masks = [sum(x.eq(val).astype(int) for x in dfs).ge(2)
         for val in vals]

pd.DataFrame(np.select(masks, vals),
             columns=A.columns, index=A.index).mask(A.eq('.'), '.')
```

Output:

```
    a  b  c
0   0  1  1
1   .  .  .
2   0  1  0
3  -1  0  0
```

Dot handled as 1/-1:

```
dfs = [A,B,C]
vals = ['.', 1, -1]
masks = [sum(x.eq(val).astype(int) for x in dfs).ge(2)
         for val in vals]
pd.DataFrame(np.select(masks, vals),
             columns=A.columns, index=A.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that there are better solutions, but you could use:

```
from collections import Counter

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c"])

for i in range(0, len(A)):
    a = 0
    temp = []
    for j in A.columns:
        count = Counter([A[j][i], B[j][i], C[j][i]]).most_common()
        if count[0][1] > 1:
            temp.append(count[0][0])
        else:
            temp.append(0)
        a+=1
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, pd.DataFrame([temp], columns=["a", "b", "c"])])
```

**Output:**

```
    a   b   c
0   0   1   1
0   .   .   .
0   0   1   0
0   -1  0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First solving the problem

1. concat the dfs
2. groupby the lower index
3. aggregate with values count keeping the first element

```
df = (pd.concat([A, B, C], axis=0, keys=['A', 'B', 'C'])
        .groupby(level=1)
        .agg(lambda x: (x.value_counts().iloc[0] >= 2) * x.value_counts().index[0])
)
```

Output

```
    a  b   c
0   0  1   1
1   .  .   .
2   0  1   0
3  -1  0   0
```

#### Cleaning the code

The line `.agg(lambda x: (x.value_counts().iloc[0] >= 2) * x.value_counts().index[0])`:

- is not fancy
- raises a warning under pandas 1.1.5:

  ```
  DeprecationWarning: In future, it will be an error for 'np.bool_' scalars to be interpreted as an index
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
  ```

With a function in replacement of the lambda we can enhance on both points:

```
def series_rule(s):
    vc = s.value_counts()
    return  vc.index[0] if (vc.iloc[0] >= 2) else 0  
    
df = (pd.concat([A, B, C], axis=0, keys=['A', 'B', 'C'])
        .groupby(level=1)
        .agg(series_rule)
)
```

#### Generalizing

We can now define a reusable function :

```
def Rachael_rule(pandas_serie):
    vc = pandas_serie.value_counts()
    return  vc.index[0] if (vc.iloc[0] >= 2) else 0  

def df_list_apply(rule, df_list):
    """
    Applies a rule to a list of dataframe of same shapes
    
    Parameters;
    - rule : a function taking a pandas.Series argument and returnig a value
    - df_list a list of pandas.DataFRame

    Return:
      the dataframe obtained by apllyng the rule on the dimenion of the list
    """    
    return (pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, keys=list(range(len(df_list))))
              .groupby(level=1)
              .agg(rule)
           )
```

Then:

```
>>> df_list_apply(Rachael_rule, [A, B, C])
[Out]
    a  b   c
0   0  1   1
1   .  .   .
2   0  1   0
3  -1  0   0
```

Comment: Great solution, but there is an error C3 should be 0.

Comment: @Marco_CH , true indeed, I do not get the rule and my solution is not giving the right result as this a multimode case. I added a comment  to clarify.

Comment: @Marco_CH : corrected